# Is it possible to accept a PhD position I previously turned down?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I rejected a PhD position five months ago with a gentle email due to unbearable family conditions at that time, that I explained to my supervisors and they understood (and maybe were bothered).

However, the position is still available, but I am a little bit puzzled if I could write to them and express interest in taking the position?

The truth is that I do not know how my profs who recommended me felt when they heard about my rejection. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ac.SE! I cleaned up the English in your question, please make sure I haven't done anything wrong. In what country is this position?

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/131397/latest-time-to-reverse-a-declined-phd-offer https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/130802/asking-for-reversing-my-decision-after-declining-a-phd-offer https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67162/i-regret-declining-a-really-good-phd-offer-can-i-ask-if-i-can-accept-the-offer https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134020/i-regret-declining-a-phd-offer-and-accepting-another-phd-offer-what-should-i-do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

You can only ask them - you cannot get the position if you don't ask.

If they understood your situation back then, they will understand that things have changed over time and that you are available now. They might be glad to hear from you, and I would think your chances are good, since they must have thought you were capable back then, and they haven't found another candidate yet (unless they do, and haven't announced it yet, or only wait for administration to finish their stuff).