# PhD rejection Change mind

Tags: phd, rejection

Last summer I turned down a PhD offer that previously had accepted. This happened due to family reasons which I explained to my supervisor.

Now I regret this decision, and I would like to join again. I send an email to the supervisor of this PhD position and the answer was that "I could apply from scratch" because the position was re-advertised.

The only I would like to know, is, if could I have possibilities to gain again this chance or the answer was merely gently responsed?

Thank you

Best regards

Comment: Recent similar question https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/180925/is-it-possible-to-accept-a-phd-position-i-previously-turned-down

Comment: My guess is that, if they decide you're the best applicant for the (re-advertised) position, they'll offer it to you. In deciding whether you're the best applicant, they might or might not take into account your "Yes ---> No ---> Yes" oscillation on their previous offer.